# Dynamically and conditionaly changing css of a button in reactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-rendering

In a react application how to dynamically change css of a button when a form input validation fails(There are lot of input fields which accept marks)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<button style={{backgroundColor: this.state.error ? 'red' : 'green'}}>Save</button>
```

or change the class based on the error state and style in the css file like this

```
<button className={this.state.error && 'error'}>Save</button>
```

Hope this helps

PS `this.state.error` assumes you are using a class component

Answer (score 0):

Also you can give `className` conditionally. If you don't want to set anything when condition is false, then just leave as empty string `''`

```
<button className={ this.state.something ? 'first-class' : 'second-class' }>Clicker</button>
```

If you want to add a className **attribute** conditionally, then

```
<button { ...(booleanValue && { className: 'some-class' }) }>Clicker</button>
```